# What is the protocol that is used to send emails?

Tags: email, smtp, imap, pop3

What is the protocol that is used to send emails from one server `@example.com` to another `@example2.com`

Comment: SMTP, just like the tag you used in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's Simple Mail Transfer Protocol, commonly known as SMTP. It was first defined in [RFC 812](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc821), but there are more recent enhancements.